# Remove the last cloned element

Tags: jquery

I have a button to clone my form, and I want to put another button to remove an specific cloned form. How can i do it?

I used the events `closest` and `remove`, but it's still not working. It removes all the forms that I have.

```
<input style='width: 60px;' type='submit' class='clone' value='+' />

    <form name='form' id='form' method='POST'>
        <input style='width: 80px;' type='submit' name='add_jo' value='Submit all' />
        <div class='cform'>

            <td><input class='txtedit' placeholder='Description' name='description[]' /></td>

        </div>
        <input class="txtedit" type="submit" class="remove" value="Cancel"/>

   </form>
```

JQuery

```
$('.clone').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var tr = $('.cform:first');
   var newTr = tr.clone();
   newTr.find(":input").val(''); //find all input types (input, textarea), empty it.
   newTr.appendTo(tr.parent());
}); 


$(".remove").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".cform").remove();
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Where is `.remove` in your HTML?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, you can't have `TD` in a `DIV`, it has to be in a `TR`.

Comment: Your remove button shouldn't remove anything. `closest()` finds looks for a containing element matching the selector, but `.remove` is not inside `.cform`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your most recently appended element should be the last, you can use an appropriate selector and get it:

```
$(".remove").click(function(e) {
    $(".cform:last-child").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```